# Use of substring within capistrano tasks

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I am rather new to capistrano. I wonder how to substring a variable within a capistrano task.

While this gives me what to expect within **irb**

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :012 > release_path = "12345678910"
 => "12345678910"
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :019 > release_path[-6..-1]
 => "678910"
```

it **does nothing** within a capistrano task

```
namespace :namespacename do
  task :taskname do

    release_path = "1234678910"
    release_path[-6..-1]

    # output is still "12345678910"
    puts release_path

  end
end
```

Anybody how to do use ruby classes/methods on variables within capistrano tasks? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's all ruby in capistrano so anything goes really:

```
namespace :namespacename do
  task :taskname do

    release_path = "1234678910"
    release_path[-6..-1]     #<----    NO!!!

    # output is "678910"
    puts release_path[-6..-1]      #<----    YEAH BOY!!!

    release_path = release_path[-6..-1]
    puts release_path       # output is "678910"

    release_path[-3..-1]   # does nothing because "910" is returned into thin air
    puts release_path[-3..-1]       # output is "910"
    puts release_path[-3..-1][-2..-1]    # output is substring of substring "10"
  end
end
```

Using the substring range syntax [x...y] it'll return it, not truncate it and store in the same variable.

HTH

Comment: First thanks for your answer. If i get it right by your code comments using _puts release_path[-6..-1]_ should make it, right? Tried this, unfortunately with same results. _release_path_ still contains the original value.

Comment: If you want to st release_path to the substring use release_path = release_path[-6..-1]  as using the [] syntax only returns it, hard to explain so i'll update my answer with some more examples of usage

Comment: The reason you see output in irb for the stuff i have marked as being "output into thin air" is because irb is very verbose and tells you what is going on for each command whether it's actually output or not

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation and examples! Finally i got it. Brilliant. Cheers.